# How to append multiple value in csv file header with python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

This is my code and I can't append value in 'Title, Ingredients, instructions, nutrients, Image, link'

```
from recipe_scrapers import scrape_me
import requests
from recipe_scrapers import scrape_html
from csv import writer



with open('recipe.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as file:

    #create new CSV file and write header that name Title ,Ingredients,instructions,nutrients,Image,link.
    thewriter = writer(file)
    header = ['Title', 'Ingredients', 'Instructions', 'Nutrition_Facts','image','links']
    thewriter.writerow(header)


url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/220751/quick-chicken-piccata/"
html = requests.get(url).content
scraper = scrape_html(html=html, org_url=url)

for scrap in scraper:
    #this loop add Title ,Ingredients,instructions,nutrients,Image,link value .
    info = ['title, Ingredients, instructions, nutrients,Image,link']
    thewriter.writerow(info)

    Title = scraper.title()
    Ingredients = scraper.ingredients()
    instructions = scraper.instructions()
    nutrients = scraper.nutrients()
    Image = scraper.image()
    link = scraper.links()
print(scrap)
```

How I can solve this code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more clear, where you do have problems?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code. Firstly, your indentation is off. You are creating `thewriter` variable in a different code block and then trying to access it in a different code block. To fix this, you will have to indent all the code below your `with open` statement to the same level.

Secondly, according to the [recipe-scrapers doc](https://pypi.org/project/recipe-scrapers/), `scraper` is an `AllRecipesCurated` object that cannot be iterated, so your line:

```
for scrap in scraper:
```

makes no sense since your trying to iterate over a non-iterable object and will give you an error.

Finally, these two lines:

```
info = ['title, Ingredients, instructions, nutrients,Image,link']
thewriter.writerow(info)
```

mean that you will always have the heading written into your file, not the data you get from the calling the URL. You should instead make it point to the data you extract from the url:

```
thewriter.writerow([scraper.title(), scraper.ingredients(), scraper.instructions(), scraper.nutrients(), scraper.image(), scraper.links()])
```

Here is the full code fixed. You should be able to get the correct results using it:

```
import requests
from recipe_scrapers import scrape_html
from csv import writer

with open('recipe.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as file:
    # create new CSV file and write header that name Title ,Ingredients,instructions,nutrients,Image,link.
    thewriter = writer(file)
    header = ['Title', 'Ingredients', 'Instructions', 'Nutrition_Facts', 'image', 'links']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/220751/quick-chicken-piccata/"
    html = requests.get(url).content
    scraper = scrape_html(html=html, org_url=url)

    thewriter.writerow([scraper.title(), scraper.ingredients(), scraper.instructions(), scraper.nutrients(), scraper.image(), scraper.links()])
```